# how to prove the relationship between pseudoconvexity and the monge-ampere matrix?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

In several complex variables , to determine the pseudoconvexity of a domain in $C^n$ is  very important . There are various criterion to decide whether a  domain is pseudoconvex . In particular ,if the domain is defined by a $C^\infty$ defining function $\phi>0$  , then 'Levi pseudoconvex ' is equivalent to the following matrix (which is called 'Monge-Ampere matrix')
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -\phi & -\partial_\bar{k}\phi   \\
-\partial_j\phi & -\partial_{j\bar{k}}^2\phi \end{pmatrix} $$
have precise one negative eigenvalue and n positive eigenvalues .

So my question is how to prove this ? Anybody knows?  Thanks  very much!

Comment: I fixed your math display. You probably should also include a definition of the notation $\partial_{\bar{k}}$ (I think I know what it is, but best to make sure), and perhaps (link to) a short description of Levi pseudoconvexity to refresh our memories. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is always nonzero inside $\Omega$ , so this matrix has precise one negative eigenvalue and n positive eigenvalues is equivalent to $-\partial\bar{\partial}log\phi$ is non-negative , but which means that $-log\phi$ is a plurisubharmonic exhaustion function for the domain $\Omega$ , i.e. $\Omega$ is pseudoconvex.